# How do I give a type to my multidimensional array

Tags: typescript

If I have a multidimensional array like this

```
const x: [][];
```

how can I specify the type of the array? Like you would with a normal array

```
const x:Array<SomeType>;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any of:

```
const arr: Array<Array<SomeType>>;

const arr: SomeType[][];
```

with initialization:

```
const arr = new Array<Array<SomeType>>();

const arr = [] as SomeType[][];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a multidimensional array by:

```
var arr_name:datatype[][]=[ [val1,val2,val3],[v1,v2,v3] ]
```